# Gradle error: package com.example.Example does not exist

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-studio, junit

I am in Android Studio, trying to create a Unit Test. I followed the instructions of the [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html), all went ok, except when I import and refer to a class of the module I want to test. For example, a test like this works:

```
 assertTrue(true);
```

but not this:

```
assertTrue(myMethod());
```

This is the build.gradle of the module I want to test:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Mylib')
    compile project(':Mylib2')
    compile project(':Mylib3')
    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    // unit testing
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
}
configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('test')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
productFlavors {
}
}
```

and this is the class "src/test/pathname/Test.java" (I followed the instructions of the tutorial to create the folder):

```
package com.my.Example;

import org.junit.Test;
import com.my.Example.foo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class Test {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        assertTrue("test", true); // this is ok
        assertTrue(myMethod());   // this not works :(
    }

}
```

where myMethod() is in Example class and returns a boolean.

How to resolve?

Comment: How can we help without seeing your project and without seeing your code?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jared, added some information.